# JSON parsing issue sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have the below json that needs to be displayed in a list (locations array). I can get the locations array with **rootProperty: response.data.locations** but how do i get the success, logo and backgroundpicture. Any suggestions would be helpfull.

```
Ext.data.JsonP.callback1(
{
    "response": {
        "success": true,
        "data": {
            "logo": "http:\\/\\/www.websiteurl.nl\\/Images\\/logo.jpg",
            "backgroundpicture": "http:\\/\\/www.websiteurl.nl\\/Images\\/logo.jpg",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "id": "47",
                    "name": " 's-Gravenzande (De Carlton)",
                    "street": "Naaldwijkseweg",
                    "number": "257",
                    "zipcode": "2691 PV",
                    "city": "'s Gravenzande",
                    "province": "9",
                    "phone": "0174-412997",
                    "email": "info@websiteurl.nl",
                    "kvk": "27210224",
                    "lat": "51.988593",
                    "longitude": "4.188087",
                    "slug": "-sGravenzande-De-Carlton",
                    "website": "http:\\/\\/www.websiteurl.nl",
                    "logo": null,
                    "backgroundpicture": null
                },
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "Achterberg",
                    "street": "Weteringsteeg",
                    "number": "12",
                    "zipcode": "3911 VN",
                    "city": "Achterberg",
                    "province": "7",
                    "phone": "0317-613643",
                    "email": "info@websiteurl.nl",
                    "kvk": "30093218",
                    "lat": "51.976316",
                    "longitude": "5.601611",
                    "slug": "-Achterberg",
                    "website": "http:\\/\\/www.websiteurl.nl",
                    "logo": null,
                    "backgroundpicture": null
                }


            ]
        }
    }
}
);
```

If i add a listner to my store and then log these things then i am getting the values but my point is how can i parse this and store this in my store

```
Ext.define("app.store.LocationStore",{
extend:'Ext.data.Store',
id: 'locationStore',

requires: 'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',

config:{
    autoLoad: 'true',
    model:'app.model.LocationModel',

    proxy:
    {
        type:'jsonp',
        url:'http://www.websiteurl.nl/API/',
        limitParam: false,
        pageParam: false,
        startParam: false,
        extraParams:
        {
            method:'general',
            token: '123456'

        },
        reader:{
            type:'json',
            successProperty: 'success',
            rootProperty: 'response.data.locations'
        }
    },
    listeners:{
        load : function()
        {console.log(this.getProxy().getReader().rawData.response.data.backgroundpicture);
            console.log(this.getProxy().getReader().rawData.response.data.logo);
            console.log(this.getProxy().getReader().rawData.response.success);
            console.log("location store loaded");
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: what is your 'store' or 'model'  rootProperty setup ?

Comment: added store code in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to structure your model according to the data structure using the [hasOne](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.association.HasOne) and [hasMany](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.association.Association) association.

```
Ext.define('myApp.model.MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields  : [
            {
                name : 'success'
            }
        ],
        hasOne : [
            {
                model          : 'myApp.model.Data,
                name           : 'data',
                associationKey : 'data'
            }
        ]
    }
});

Ext.define('myApp.model.Data, {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields  : [
            {
                name : 'logo'
            },
            {
                name : 'backgroundpicture'
            }
        ],
        hasMany : [
            {
                model          : 'myApp.model.Location',
                name           : 'locations',
                associationKey : 'locations'
            }
        ]
    }
});

Ext.define('myApp.model.Location', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields  : [
            {
                name : 'id'
            },
            {
                name : 'name'
            },
            {
                name : 'street'
            }
    ...to be continued...
```

Comment: Also how do i get the successProperty value?

Comment: Modified answer to include hasOne association to get success

Comment: location model values to my list. can you please show me its store and list as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use simple JSONP request to populate data and add them into the store. It will be something like this:

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
     url:'http://www.websiteurl.nl/API/',
     callbackKey: 'callback',
     params: {
         method:'general',
         token: '123456'
     },
     success: function(result, request) {
          //result.response.success
          //result.response.data.logo
          //result.response.data.backgroundpicture
          store.add(result.response.data.locations);
     }
});
```